# Getting the following error, any tips to resolving it? I am trying to convert from OAM to OKTA for authentication

Tags: spring, tomcat, oauth-2.0, okta

I have a Spring application that I’ve been trying to switch over to Okta. I have not made it connect with OKTA yet. I am getting an error related to client registration.
I am using following dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <!-- <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>-->
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <!--<version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Application.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta.issuer-uri=https://dev-327711.okta.com/oauth2/default
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.provider=okta
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-name=awards2
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-id=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-secret=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.redirect-uri=/authorization-code/callback
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.scope=openid,profile,email
```

Error trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration$Builder;
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading OAuth2 document I resolved this issue by adding "autoconfigure" dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/